# get every textblock from listview

Tags: c#, xaml

I'm building a `UWP` app and I'm trying to get every textblock from my `listview`.

This is my `listview`:

```
                <ListView Grid.Row="1" BorderBrush="#0062AD" BorderThickness="1" ItemsSource="{Binding BusRoutes}" x:Name="Routes1" SelectionMode="None"   IsItemClickEnabled="False"  Padding="0 10 0 0">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid Width="400">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <TextBlock x:Name="startingPoint" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"  Padding="0 10 0 10" TextAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding hours}"/>
                            <TextBlock TextAlignment="Center"  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"  Padding="0 10 0 10" x:Name="endingPoint" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding hours2}" />
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
```

And this is my attempt of doing this:

```
    public T FindElementByName<T>(DependencyObject element, string sChildName) where T : FrameworkElement
    {
        T childElement = null;
        var nChildCount = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(element);
        for (int i = 0; i < nChildCount; i++)
        {
            FrameworkElement child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(element, i) as FrameworkElement;

            if (child == null)
                continue;

            if (child is T && child.Name.Equals(sChildName))
            {
                childElement = (T)child;
                break;
            }

            childElement = FindElementByName<T>(child, sChildName);

            if (childElement != null)
                break;
        }
        return childElement;
    }
```

And in my ItemClick event I did this:

```
        this.UpdateLayout();

        for (int i = 0; i < Routes1.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            var container = this.Routes1.ContainerFromIndex(i);
            TextBlock endingPoint = FindElementByName<TextBlock>(container, "endingPoint");
            endingPoint.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < Routes1.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            var container = this.Routes1.ContainerFromIndex(i);
            TextBlock startingPoint = FindElementByName<TextBlock>(container, "startingPoint");
            startingPoint.SetValue(Grid.ColumnSpanProperty, 2);
        }
```

and I'm getting `System.ArgumentException`. The weird thing is that when I'm trying to take one `textblock` eg `var container = this.Routes1.ContainerFromIndex(0);`

I can get the first textblock normally. Why is this happening?

I forgot to mention that the exception blows up at this line:

```
var nChildCount = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(element);
```

Comment: Can you put the exception message with more details ?

Comment: An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in App1.exe but was not handled in user code

WinRT information: reference

Additional information: The parameter is incorrect.

Comment: There you go. It itself says the parameter is incorrect. Double check on your method call and parameters and the actual method implementations. The signatures should match.